# Removing specific characters and print in separate lines

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I need your urgent help and guidance, I have a file in which there is 1000s of sequences , from which I want to cleave K and R and paste the remaining sequences line by line.
File A:

```
MSTNPKPQRK  TKRNTNRRPE  DVKFPGGQI
```

Desired Output:

```
MSTNP
PQ
T
NTN
PE
DV
FPGGQI
```

After getting this output I want to search individual sequences in file B (database of sequences)

Comment: This seems like a very good question for [Code Golf](codegolf.stackexchange.com). Do you mind if I ask this on code golf? @fia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/[KR[:blank:]]\+/\n/g' A.txt
```

- `sed 's/[KR[:blank:]]\+/\n/g' A.txt` substitute all one or more `K`, `R`, and space/tab with newline from `A.txt`

---

With `awk`:

```
awk -F '[KR[:blank:]]+' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}' A.txt
```

- `-F '[KR[:blank:]]+'` sets the field separator as one or more `K`, `R`, space/tab
- `{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}` iterates over and prints the fields

---

You can leverage `awk` for searching resulting patterns on another file by using the two files as arguments, and working from there.

More generic would be to use `grep` to take patterns from an input filename, you can use process substitution to get a file descriptor:

```
grep -f <(awk/sed ... A.txt) B.txt
```

For exact match, add `-F`:

```
grep -Ff <(awk/sed ... A.txt) B.txt
```

---

**Example:**

```
% cat A.txt 
MSTNPKPQRK  TKRNTNRRPE  DVKFPGGQI

% sed 's/[KR[:blank:]]\+/\n/g' A.txt
MSTNP
PQ
T
NTN
PE
DV
FPGGQI

% awk -F '[KR[:blank:]]+' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}' A.txt 
MSTNP
PQ
T
NTN
PE
DV
FPGGQI
```

Comment: Dear heemayl,I really appreciate your spontaneous reply can you do me one more favor what if I want to print these with K,R likewise:
MSTNPK
PQRK
TKR
NTNRR

Comment: @fia Here: `sed -E 's/[KR[:blank:]]+/&\n/g' A.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Obtaining desired output can be done in several different ways. Perl and Awk presented below work in exactly same manner. You can redirect either command using `>` operator to file and then use `grep -f pattern.txt data.txt`

For instance, with perl presented below, we can do:

```
 perl -ne '@s=split /[KR ]/,$_; foreach(@s){ print "$_\n" if !/^$/}'  input.txt  > pattern.txt && grep -f pattern.txt data.txt
```

#### Perl

The perl approach is effectivelly the same as AWK explained below: split line into columns using K,R, and space as separators then iterate over all of them printing only non-empty columns.

```
$ perl -ne '@s=split /[KR ]/,$_; foreach(@s){ print "$_\n" if !/^$/}'  input.txt          
MSTNP
PQ
T
NTN
PE
DV
FPGGQI
```

#### AWK

```
$ awk -F '[KR ]' 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"};{$1=$1;print}' input.txt  | awk '!/^$/'                              
MSTNP
PQ
T
NTN
PE
DV
FPGGQI
```

Key points of how this works:

- `-F` allows us to use space,K and R as separators for columns(aka fields).
- `BEGIN{OFS="\n"}` allows us to use newline as output separator so that the items come out separated by newline
- To apply the new OFS we trigger rebuilding of text line via `$1=$1` assignment, and finally print the line.
- due to multiple column separators K,R, and space being adjacent  (for example in `PQRK`) we have to filter out empty lines from the first awk, which is what the second awk is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `K`,`R`, and whitespace characters with newlines, squeezing any multiple instances:

```
$ tr -s '[KR[:space:]]' '\n' < file
MSTNP
PQ
T
NTN
PE
DV
FPGGQI
```